# Less noise when not following LED Driver datasheet

Tags: noise, constant-current, led-driver

I designed a board which uses a LED driver ([datasheet](http://www.meanwell.com/mw_search/LDH-45/LDH-45-SPEC.PDF)).

It clearly states, DO NOT connect DIM- to Vin-:

[image]

However, these are the waveforms I get on Analog DIM pin when they are disconnected, and connected:

(I'm using a DAC to drive Analog DIM, the DAC is fed from a linear regulator that is conected to Vin- and Vin+.)

[image]

Clearly cleaner with the pins connected:

[image]

I measured the pins of the LED driver for continuity and Vin-/DIM- ARE connected to each other inside the driver.

Why would the datasheet recommend not connecting them then? I really dont understand this. I'm considering leaving the pins connected on the PCB aswell for way less noise.

**UPDATE**

So experimenting I arrived at a solution which gives the least amount of noise in the DAC.

I added ferrites between DAC ground and Driver ground and DAC PSU V+ and Driver V+.

After this I grounded the DIM- pin to DAC ground.

This leads me to speculate that inside the driver DIM- and VIn- are also connected through ferrites (otherwise after connecting DIM- to DAC ground noise would also be present, but it wasnt)

Comment: Can you share a photo of the physical construction of your circuit?

Comment: Also, when you measure the output waveform, how are you grounding the scope probe?

Comment: @ThePhoton http://imgur.com/Os1DuQJ The unsoldered pin is PWM input, which I'm not using. Wire is for i2c pullup since board is not fully populated yet.

Comment: I tried using normal GND lead and short lead (~10mm). Shorter gets less noise but its still there.

Comment: But you grounded it to the main circuit ground? Can you do a differential measurement between Vout+ and Vout-?

Comment: I grounded it to output capacitor of the linear regulator that feeds the DAC (~3mm from dac ground)

Comment: Since Vin-, DIM-, and Vout- are not connected, it's possible that you're seeing common mode signal on Vout+ that also appears on Vout-, so it wouldn't affect the current through the LEDs.

Comment: That measurement/noise is on Analog DIM pin, not on Vout, sorry for not clarifying. I'll edit my post.

Comment: @ThePhoton - I measured the Vout+/-  with two probes grounded together and subtracted them on the scope, Peak-to-peak noise looks about ~1V, in sync with the noise on the DAC.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to bark up the same tree as Photon did.

What connection is made to the DIM- pin nominally?  Is it a trace run back to the ground pin of the DAC?

Is this noise present directly at the DAC output with respect to its immediate ground as well?

Comment: Nominally DIM- is not connected to anything since datasheet told me ~not~ to connect it to Vin-, but in practice its connected to Vin- through the driver itself (this is what is confusing me). This noise is present directly at the DAC output, measuring from ground directly at its coupling capacitor.

Comment: Ah.  I may be incorrect but I believe you may have misunderstood what they meant.  I believe they meant do not connect them directly together at the driver chip, not that they cannot be connected to the same net. I think what they would want you to do is simply run traces from the DAC ground and output directly as a roughly differential pair to the analog dim+ and Dim- and do the same with the traces leaving the driving outputs heading to the LED.  Then you would presumably just connect vin- and vin+ to your ground and power planes directly if you have them.

Comment: Thinking on it further, it would be silly in a sense if they had those pins labeled and all just to tell you to float them completely... Rather than just calling them NC pins

Comment: Ahh, chinese datasheets, so confusing. So the point is, I should route Dim- to as directly as possible to DAC ground area, and then connect the DAC ground to a "star" point? As in, splitting "digital" and analog grounds?

Comment: First part, yes. Second part, I would just consult DAC datasheet.  I think it will tell you to just ground it as directly as possible to a low inductance ground plane.